# How to stop React Player from playing when close modal?

Tags: reactjs, video-player, react-player

I am using React Player npm install for React project. The video player is in a modal.  How do I stop it from playing when the modal closes?  Is there a `ReactPlayer.stop()` or a `ReactPlayer.pause()` type of functionality that I can add in my `hideModal` function?

```
<Modal show={this.state.show} handleClose={this.hideModal} >               
<ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' width='100%'
height='100%' />
</Modal>
```

Comment: Please check my answer, does this works for you?

Comment: That worked!! thank you so much for the great solve!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `this.state.show` returns Boolean value (true/false) you could control it through state like that:

```
<ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' playing={this.state.show} width='100%' height='100%' />
```

Comment: Great to hear that!

Comment: this solution pauses the video. How about to 'STOP' the video?

Answer (score 1):

viciousP has the correct answer, but I think it's worth showing the full code example so others can see exactly how this works.

Using the State Hook

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

function Video() {

    const video_source = "https://vimeo.com/blahblah";

    function close_video() {
        setPlay(false)
    }

    const [play, setPlay] = useState(true);

    return(
        <ReactPlayer id="video" url={video_source} playing={play}/>
    )

}

export default Video;
```

Now you can programmatically stop the video from playing by calling `close_video()`

Answer (score 0):

For me better works this example, key point to use together onPlay, onPause and playing prop

```
function VideoModal({ isShow, onClose, source }: any) {
  const [isPlaying, setPlaying] = useState(false)
  

  return (
    <AppModal 
      onClose={() => {
        setPlaying(false)
        onClose()
      }}
      isShow={isShow}
    >
        <ReactPlayer
          playing={isPlaying} 
          height='100%' 
          width="100%" 
          controls={true} 
          onPlay={() => setPlaying(true)}
          onPause={() => setPlaying(false)}
          url={source} 
        />
    </AppModal>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem: mount and unmount the modal based on true/false state value

eg: instead of

```
<Modal show={this.state.show} handleClose={this.hideModal} >               
<ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' width='100%'
height='100%' />
</Modal>
```

do this

```
{ (this.state.show) ? <Modal show={this.state.show} handleClose={this.hideModal} >               
<ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' width='100%'
height='100%' />
</Modal> 
: null }
```

This way you can mount and unmount Modal and stop the video from playing when the modal closes.